# Python for NLTK in Excel file

Tags: python, nltk

I would like to analyze text data in an Excel file.
I know how I could read an Excel file via Python, but each piece of data becomes one value of a list. However, I would like to analyze text in each cell.

Here is my example of the Excel file:

```
NAME    INDUSTRY        INFO    
A       FINANCIAL       THIS COMPANY IS BLA BLA BLA 
B       MANUFACTURE     IT IS LALALALALALALALALA    
C       FINANCIAL       THAT IS SOSOSOSOSOSOSOSO    
D       AGRICULTURE     WHYWHYWHYWHYWHY
```

I would like to analyze, say, the financial industry's company info using NLTK, such as the frequency of "IT".

This is what I have so far (yes, it doesn't work!):

```
import xlrd
aa='c:/book3.xls'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(aa)
wb.sheet_names()
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
     print nltk.word_tokenize(sh.row_values(rownum))
```

Comment: What doesn't work? There could be tons of ways that it "doesn't work". Can you give us an error code (the whole traceback), or the unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing all values in a row to word_tokenize but you are only interested in what is in the 3rd column. You are also processing the header row. Try this:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("your_input_file.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): # skip heading row
    name, industry, info = sheet.row_values(row_index, end_colx=3)
    print "Row %d: name=%r industry=%r info=%r" %
        (row_index + 1, name, industry, info)
    print nltk.word_tokenize(info) # or whatever else you want to do
```